# Difference between [休日]{きゅうじつ}, [休暇]{きゅうか} and 休{やす}み

Tags: word-choice, meaning, usage

What is the difference between 休日, 休暇 and 休み? When each should be used?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

休日 and 休暇 mean *a day off*. 休み sometimes means *a day off*, but also means *taking a rest*.

It seems 休日 is a day off under the company/school's regulations: Like Saturdays, Sundays and national holidays. 休暇 is a day off that is not stipulated by your school/company's regulations, but you apply for a day off and they approve it.

From my personal experience, people don't distinguish between 休日 and 休暇 strictly. They just mean *a day off*.

Answer (score 4):

Adding to @Takashi's great answer, you need to note that [[休]{やす}み](http://jisho.org/search/%E3%82%84%E3%81%99%E3%81%BF) has a lot of meanings (take a look at the link) that include both 休{きゅう}日{じつ}, 休{きゅう}暇{か}. For example:

> [夏休]{なつやす}み: summer vacation, summer holidays.

If you want to use 休{きゅう}暇{か}, you have to use [暑中休暇]{しょちゅうきゅうか} which is not as broadly used as [夏休]{なつやす}み and サマー・バケーション. As commented below, [夏期]{かき}休暇 and [夏季]{かき}休暇 are used, too.

[休日]{きゅうじつ} could be the opposite of [平日]{へいじつ} which means weekday (non-holiday, Monday to Friday).

They might look similar, but their usages could be different. You should check example phrases and sentences in the dictionary and learn them.

Comment: `暑中休暇` -> 普通は「[夏期]{かき}休暇/[夏季]{かき}休暇」っていいますね・・

Comment: @chocolate Thanks for the comment. I edited my answer. Please feel free to edit it.

Comment: Thanks for answers indeed. The 夏期休暇 and 夏季休暇 raises another question :) - can I simply translate them as "Summer season vacation" and "Summer time vacation" respectively? Is it the main difference (season vs time/period)?

Comment: @ErnestasGruodis They basically have the same meaning and I don't think you need to include "season" and "time/period" as they seem redundant.

Comment: Maybe I just digging too deep :)

Comment: @ErnestasGruodis Well, if you are learning each Chinese characters by digging too deep, it helps you to learn the language.

Answer (score 1):

休み: a rest
休暇: a day (or days) off work when it is not a holiday.
休日: a day off or a holiday

http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/221894/meaning/m0u/%E4%BC%91%E3%81%BF/
http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/54761/meaning/m0u/%E4%BC%91%E6%9A%87/
http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/55017/meaning/m0u/%E4%BC%91%E6%97%A5/

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add that 休み is more informal than 休日. You can also say 休みます = I'm resting

Comment: I guess "I'm resting" is 休んでいます?