# 夏期休暇　夏季休暇　暑中休暇　夏休み

Tags: words

I just read in a book 暑中休暇 and wondered the difference with the three others, but there is nothing on Google that really explains what the nuance is.

I think 夏休み is like the most general, 暑中休暇 maybe is the most literary (?), and I've only seen the others in 新聞s.

Anyway, I'm hoping someone could give me a real explanation on how to use the four words properly, and if there are english equivalents.

Thanks!

Comment: related, maybe? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/40014/9831

Comment: I'm really confused about what you're asking.  Is 暑中休暇 the title of a book?  From the way you wrote it, that's what it looks like.  But, I suspect you mean something else.  Are you asking about different ways to say "summer break" and the differences between those expressions?  If so, please try to be a bit more explicit.

Comment: Well I don't know how I could be more clear, I saw this word in "kokoro" (natsume soseki), a part of the sentence is : 暑中休暇を利用して海水浴に行った友達 [...].  Anyway, I was just asking what the difference between the four is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- 夏季休暇 and 夏期休暇 are both common and sound formal. The difference between 夏季 and 夏期 is often not important, but since the kanji 季 means *season* and the kanji 期 means *period*, 夏季 tends to be used when the hot climate is important. See: [夏季休暇？　夏期休暇？](https://www.nhk.or.jp/bunken/summary/kotoba/term/063.html)
- 夏休み is another very common word, and is relatively colloquial. 夏休み is the default word at elementary school, and it's also common among adults in casual speech.
- 暑中休暇 is instantly understandable, but uncommon as a set phrase. Maybe some companies are using this term.